# Without using jQuery, how can I get inputs by type?

Tags: javascript

I know I can call:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Do I need to loop through and check the attributes for type == "text" ?

I know jQuery has `input[type="text"]`. 
Is there any plain JavaScript way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got it mostly correct - *unless* the code is running in [a browser which supports `querySelectorAll`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13). Here's the cross-browser code:

```
var textInputs;
if (document.querySelectorAll)
{
    textInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
}
else
{
    textInputs = [];
    var unfiltered = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        i = unfiltered.length,
        input;
    while(i--)
    {
        input = unfiltered[i];
        if (!input.type || input.type === 'text')
        {
            textInputs.push(input);
        }
    }
}
```

**N.B.** in the `else` case, I check for the truthiness of `input.type` in case the input looks like this:

```
<input />
```

in which case it *defaults* `type="text"`. I **only** included this because I'm not 100% sure if every browser will return `"text"` when the attribute is left off. For the record, at least Chrome does. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/jJsjn/

Comment: hi matt, is there a good source for seeing a list of these browser method capabilities and their support?

Comment: Of course! It sounds like you might have missed the link to quirksmode in my answer, so here it is again: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13

Comment: Chrome returns `text` when you leave it out, but you can't use it in querySelector it seems like. Updated your fiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/rLq6xjb5/

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it :)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for(var e in elements)
{
    if(e.type == "text")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's available to you, you can use the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/).

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a sizzlejs-specific not jquery itself. And yes, dropping jquery is for good. DOM0 collections will perform this task in the best way:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++ )
  for ( var j = 0; j < document.form[i].elements.length; j++ )
    /* have to do case-insensitive match to support any DOCTYPE */
    if ( document.form[i].elements[j].type.toUpperCase() == 'TEXT' )
      document.form[i].elements[j] = 'HAI!'; 
      /* done! */
```